# Jquery - Listas ordenadas botón para eliminar items

Tags: php, html, jquery, html5, jquery-ui

Tengo un código con jquery que me genera dos listas drag and drop, donde puedo mover elementos de la derecha a izquierda(esto me funciona) el problema lo tengo cuando quiero generar un botón para cada item de "borrar" como identificar cada elemento "li" para poder borrarlo.

Tengo algo como esto

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

El html resultante es este

```html
<ol class="ui-sortable">
                        
  <li data-id="2" class="ui-draggable ui-draggable-handle newClass">
  <div style="min-height: 50px;min-width: 100px">
  <div style="float:left" class="titleField">Campo de Foto</div>
  <div style="float:right" class="btnDeleteItem">
  <button class="btn btn-warning">Eliminar</button>
  </div>
  </div>
  </li>

  <li data-id="3" class="ui-draggable ui-draggable-handle newClass">
  <div style="min-height: 50px;min-width: 100px">
  <div style="float:left" class="titleField">Campo de Firma</div>
  <div style="float:right" class="btnDeleteItem">
  <button class="btn btn-warning">Eliminar</button></div>
  </div>
  </li>

  <li data-id="3" class="ui-draggable ui-draggable-handle newClass">
  <div style="min-height: 50px;min-width: 100px">
  <div style="float:left" class="titleField">Campo de Firma</div>
  <div style="float:right" class="btnDeleteItem">
  <button class="btn btn-warning">Eliminar</button></div>
  </div>
  </li>
  
</ol>
```

Desde jquery puedo capturar la acción del botón de esta forma y borrar el "li"

```
        $(document).on('click', '.btnDeleteItem', function(event) {
        $("li").find("[data-id='***id***']").remove();
    });
```

Aquí lo que me faltaría que no consigo como hacer es conseguir el atributo "data-id" de cada elemento

Gracias

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Podes obtener el `data-id` del `li` utilizando así:

- Obtenes el elemento del DOM *clic-ado* utilizando [`event.currentTarget`](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/API/Event/currentTarget)
- Buscas el `li` **ancestro más cercano al elemento** utilizando [`jQuery.closest`](https://api.jquery.com/closest/)

#### Ejemplo:

```js
$(document).on('click', '.btnDeleteItem', function(event) {
  let $li = $(event.currentTarget).closest("li");
  $li.remove();
  console.log($li.data('id'));
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ol class="ui-sortable">

  <li data-id="2" class="ui-draggable ui-draggable-handle newClass">
    <div style="min-height: 50px;min-width: 100px">
      <div style="float:left" class="titleField">Campo de Foto</div>
      <div style="float:right" class="btnDeleteItem">
        <button class="btn btn-warning">Eliminar</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </li>

  <li data-id="3" class="ui-draggable ui-draggable-handle newClass">
    <div style="min-height: 50px;min-width: 100px">
      <div style="float:left" class="titleField">Campo de Firma</div>
      <div style="float:right" class="btnDeleteItem">
        <button class="btn btn-warning">Eliminar</button></div>
    </div>
  </li>

  <li data-id="3" class="ui-draggable ui-draggable-handle newClass">
    <div style="min-height: 50px;min-width: 100px">
      <div style="float:left" class="titleField">Campo de Firma</div>
      <div style="float:right" class="btnDeleteItem">
        <button class="btn btn-warning">Eliminar</button></div>
    </div>
  </li>

</ol>
```

Comment: Muchas gracias @Marcos